How to increase the amount of time Android speech recognition listens for?
I want to increase the amount of time Android speech recognition.
I tried these 3 tags but it not working.
TAG 1: EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS
TAG 2: EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS
TAG 3: EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 10000);           intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 5000);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER);
